# onion-monero-blockchain-explorer together with Apache webserver

Tags: block-explorer

I have installed [onion-monero-blockchain-explorer](https://github.com/moneroexamples/onion-monero-blockchain-explorer/issues?page=3&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aclosed) and I am running website using Apache. Explorer listens on port 8081, but I would like to have it on standard www port 80(443) as virtualhost/subdomain. Is it possible? Is there a way how to have website and the explorer working together and reachable from restricted  proxy/work networks?

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: It seems reverse proxy could do what I need. Anyway, your ideas, best practices or experiences still welcome.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://monero.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://monero.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/5734)

Comment: You probably should take a look on https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html
Simply run your Apache on the standard ports and the explorer on 8081, then configure the subdomain to proxy localhost:8081

Answer (score 1):

Not a Monero question, but the answer can be found in Apache [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html).

```
ProxyPass "/"  "http://www.example.com/"
ProxyPassReverse "/"  "http://www.example.com/"
```

Replacing `www.example.com` with `127.0.0.1:8081`.